# Time stopped when I use mongoose with default: new Date()

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My node version is 6.11.4, and mongoose version is 4.12.4.
I only show the `createTime` field in `users` schema here.

```
createTime: {
    type: Date,
    default: new Date()
}
```

When I called a `userCreate(user)` method to create a user document, and an exception appeared like this.

```
userCreate(user);
console.log(undefined.name);
```

This document was created and the createTime field was correct.
However, when I run this two lines again, the new document's createTime was stuck as the last document's createTime.
I don't know if this is a javascript feature or I used mongoose in a wrong way.
Anyone could help me?

Answer (score -1):

I noticed this too. I tried setting the default value before calling save on the Model and it seems to work just fine. I intend to research why this happens.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please don't post "me too" replies, they don't add any value to the site.